# Pojo class can not connect to DB table--Querydsl JDO

Tags: java, spring, maven, jdo, querydsl

I am building one maven project using JDO, Querydsl. It can not connect to DB property and also there is no error so that i can understand just if i get log of any field its showing NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION.

My pojo classes are: User.java

```
@PersistenceCapable//(table = "user_login")
public class User_Login {  
//@Column(name="user_id")
private Integer user_id=0;
//@Column(name="user_profile_name")
private String user_profile_name=null; 
//@Column(name="user_email")
private String user_email=null;
//@Column(name="user_contact")
private String user_contact=null;
//@Column(name="user_name")
private String user_name=null;
//@Column(name="user_password")
private String user_password=null;
//@Column(name="user_role_id")
private Integer user_role_id=0;

//getter setter method
```

DAOImpl class:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public User_Login getUser(String username, String userpassword) {
    PersistenceManager pm = this.persistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();


    // serialization templates
    //SQLTemplates templates = new MySQLTemplates(); 

    QUser_Login user = QUser_Login.user_Login;
    //QRole role = QRole.role1;

    //JDOSQLQuery query = new JDOSQLQuery(pm, templates);
    JDOQuery query = new JDOQuery(pm);
    try {
    // Start the transaction
    tx.begin(); 
    log.info("hereeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    User_Login result = query.from(user)
                        .where(user.user_name.eq(username), 
           user.user_password.eq(userpassword)).uniqueResult(user);
    log.info("hereeeeeeeeeeeeeee 2");
    log.info(query.toString());
    log.info(result.getUserName());

    //.innerJoin(role).on(user.userRoleId.eq(role.roleId))

    if(result.getUserId()>0){
        log.info(">>>>>00000000");
    }else{
        log.info("<<<<<<<=====000000");
    }
    // Commit the transaction, flushing the object to the datastore
    tx.commit();
    return result;
    }
    finally {
        if (tx.isActive())
        {
            // Error occurred so rollback the transaction
            tx.rollback();
        }
        query.close();
        pm.close();
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>jstl</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId> 
        <version>1.2</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>            
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-jdo</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0-m3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0-m3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0-m3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                  <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jdo.JDOAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>export</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>            
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <jdbcDriver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbcDriver>
              <jdbcUrl>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login</jdbcUrl>
              <jdbcUser>root</jdbcUser>
              <packageName>com.titas.model</packageName>
              <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder> 
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.6</version>
              </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>        
    </plugins>
```

Servlet.xml

```
<!-- declare mvc to be annotation driven -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<!-- provide Your Base package to scan annotations for components -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.titas"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
 <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations-->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--The index controller.-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

<bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login"
    p:username="root"
    p:password="" />

<!-- PMF Bean -->
<bean id="myPmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jdo.LocalPersistenceManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jdoPropertyMap">
            <props>
                <prop key="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass">org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory</prop>
                <prop key="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login</prop>
                <prop key="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName">root</prop>
                <prop key="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead">true</prop>
                <prop key="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues">false</prop>
                <prop key="javax.jdo.option.DetachAllOnCommit">true</prop>
                <prop key="javax.jdo.option.Multithreaded">true</prop>
                <prop key="datanucleus.appengine.ignorableMetaDataBehavior">NONE</prop>
            </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--<bean id="pmfProxy" class="org.springframework.orm.jdo.TransactionAwarePersistenceManagerFactoryProxy">
<property name="targetPersistenceManagerFactory" ref="myPmf"/>
<property name="allowCreate" value="false"/>
</bean>  --> 


<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jdo.JdoTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceManagerFactory" ref="myPmf"/>
</bean>



<bean id="userDAO" class="com.titas.dao.UserDAOImpl" >
</bean>
```

Comment: What is the error/exception you experience?

Comment: after query if i am trying to log this-> log.info(result.getUserName()); its ahowing nullpointer exception. and generated sql is:
select user_login from user_login where user_login.user_name=? and user_login.user_password=? but it should be select user_id from user_login where user_login.user_name=? and user_login.user_password=? or select * from user_login where user_login.user_name=? and user_login.user_password=?